# IIS не работает CreateDirectory()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Не могу понять почему в IIS Asp.Net не работает System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory, саму процедуру он проходит без ошибок, но при попытки обратиться к указанной папки сообщает что её нет, что собственно правда.

```
                string folderMY = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + "/";
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("~/Files/" + folderMY);
```

Comment: `"~/Files/` - а что так можно было? Насколько помню, это в юниксах тильда обозначает домашний каталог, а чтоб в винде так же было что-то не припомню.

Comment: Когда вылетает ошибка с расположением оно в полне корректное, только не существует папка

Comment: @Bulson В ASP.Net тильда указывает на рабочий каталог приложения, даже в Windows.

Comment: @Сергей А сама папка создается? Попробуйте убрать ` + "/"` в конце.

Comment: "~/Files/" уже создана а folderMY  не создаётся

Comment: да глупая ошибка, теперь вылетает отказано в доступе IIS

Comment: Запустите пул iis от юзера с нужными правами.